# Catalog Inventory Stock Indexer not working

Tags: magento2.3, indexer

I have an issue with the cataloginventory_stock index.

```
Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table '/cataloginventory_stock_status_outdated' already exists, query was: RENAME TABLE cataloginventory_stock_status TO cataloginventory_stock_status_outdated,cataloginventory_stock_status_replica TO cataloginventory_stock_status,cataloginventory_stock_status_outdated TO cataloginventory_stock_status_replica
```

Can anyone help me for this?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: try to backup database and follow error instructions.

Comment: When trying to reindexing